# AWS Kendra get _document_body attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kendra

I'm trying to query aws kendra but I need to have the document_body in the ResultItem response.

I tried with the RequestedDocumentAttributes param in the QueryCommand but the result still not contains the document body.

```
const command = new QueryCommand({
    IndexId: 'xxxxxxx',
    QueryText: "How to connect to ec2?",
    RequestedDocumentAttributes: [
        "_document_body",
        "_data_source_id",
        "_last_updated_at"
    ]    
});
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_document_body is a special field and Kendra currently does not support returning its entire value in the Query response. Kendra does returns a [DocumentExcept](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/API_QueryResultItem.html#Kendra-Type-QueryResultItem-DocumentExcerpt) for each document ResultItem, which contains the most relevant extract of text in the _document_body.